# A regex for matching closing tags in a HTML string

Tags: python, html, regex

Suppose, I have a html *string*. I want to match the ending tag of all the `<code>` tags in it (for some manipulation of the content in between). Currently I am using this:

```py
import re
code_tags = re.finditer("<code>(?!<pre>)(?P<content>.+)(?<!</pre>)</code>", some_html_string, re.DOTALL)
```

It works fine until there is only one `code` tag in the whole string but fails miserably when there are multiple of them.

For example:

```
>>> def code_in_between(string):
...     texts = []
...     for code in re.finditer("<code>(?!<pre>)(?P<content>.+)(?<!</pre>)</code>", string, re.DOTALL):
...             texts.append(code.groupdict()['content'])
...     return texts
... 
>>> code_in_between("<code>Some code</code>")
['Some code']
>>> code_in_between("<code>Some code</code> Normal text <code> More code </code>")
['Some code</code> Normal text <code> More code ']
```

How can I get the exact closing tag for a given tag? (For some reason I am not allowed to use the `xml` library)

(It is safe to assume that there are no nested tags)

Comment: Why not BeuatifulSoup? Also, if you say you can only use `re`, please provide more reasoning about it (right now, we see you code in Python directly, it is not an external app using Python `re`), and provide a real-life sample HTML string. Also, can the tags be nested? What do you mean by "exact closing tag for a given tag"?

Comment: As for why only `re` can be used, its a part of a school project which is meant to be completed under a limited set of modules and packages and thus `re` was the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex `(?<=<code>).*?(?=</code>)`:

```
import re

print(re.findall('(?<=<code>).*?(?=</code>)', "<code>Some code</code> Normal text <code> More code </code>"))
```

Output:

```
['Some code', ' More code ']
```

If you want to only get the content inside of the `<code>` tags that don't have `<pre>` tags in them:

```
import re

lst = re.findall('(?<=<code>).*?(?=</code>)', "<code>Some code</code> Normal text <code> More code </code>")
print([s for s in lst if not any(r in s for r in ['<pre>', '</pre>'])])
```

Not a very good way of avoiding `<pre>` tags, but it gets the job done...

Try `pip install lxml` to get it working.